# how to return a response from a curl multi handle c++ libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

php has multi_get_content(), but i do not see any clear way to retrieve the response from a multi transfer when complete. I can only retrieve the CURLcode from it using the CURLMsg* variable (msg->data.result).

Comment: What makes this into a C++ question? If it is, please show a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) option to setup a callback that receives all incoming data and stores it appropriately. An example of such callback that stores the entire response in memory is [getinmemory.c](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) (While that example uses the easy interface, the callback works the exact same way for the multi interface.)